# How to make report by export data into PDF file in django?

Tags: python, django

I want to make report in django to export data as a PDF, excel or csv file. I'm looking forward a library support it in django. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

To export as PDF you could use this [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/) and this [django-wkhtmltopdf](https://github.com/incuna/django-wkhtmltopdf) you could create a template with the info and use wkhtmltopdf to export the template as PDF

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can start from the Django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/outputting-pdf/